# JSONRPC Java implementation

Tags: java, json

I've found tons of JSONRPC Java implementations out there, most of them quite old. Hence my question: which library is up to date and futureproof?

Answer (score 0):

JPoxy (at http://code.google.com/p/jpoxy/) seems to be up-to-date and under active development.